# How to pop a text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pop a centered text for 3 sec as a communicate without changing anything in screen. Everything stays the same, just showing a text for a few secs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast 
code snippet

```
fToast.showToast(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      toastDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  FToast fToast;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fToast = FToast();
    fToast.init(context);
  }

  void _showMessage() {
    fToast.showToast(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
            Text("Hello"),
            Text("World"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      toastDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _showMessage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```